# Count every instance of an item in a list of lists and sum them

Tags: python, list

In Python 3.x, I have a list of lists:

```
[['a','b','c'], ['a', 'c'], ['c', 'd'] ]
```

I saw [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2600191/how-can-i-count-the-occurrences-of-a-list-item#answer-5829377), but it only applies to a single list. How would I do this for a list of lists? My desired output would be a sorted list (or a sortable list) of the frequency of a particular item in a list.

Something like:

```
{a: 2, b: 1, c: 3, d: 1 }
```

Comment: [How to make a flat list out of list of lists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/how-to-make-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists)

Comment: Okay, so make a flat list, then run the Collections method on it?

Comment: Yes, make a flat [iterable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/953097/1324033)

Comment: No need to flatten the list to count it.

Comment: @Salt - Correct, you make an iterator that you can use within counter, no need to make a for loop either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may be solved using [Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter). Counter creates a dictionary of the counts of the elements in the lists.

```
L = [['a','b','c'], ['a', 'c'], ['c', 'd'] ]
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> d = Counter()
>>> for sub in L:
    d.update(sub)


>>> d
Counter({'c': 3, 'a': 2, 'b': 1, 'd': 1})
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use `itertools.chain(*l)` as an input to the `Counter`.

```
>>> l= [['a','b','c'], ['a', 'c'], ['c', 'd'] ]
>>> Counter(itertools.chain(*l))
Counter({'c': 3, 'a': 2, 'b': 1, 'd': 1})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Counter` from `collections` to do this very efficiently:

```
In [161]: from collections import Counter
     ...: 
     ...: count = Counter()
     ...: 
     ...: lists = [['a','b','c'], ['a', 'c'], ['c', 'd']]
     ...: 
     ...: for sublist in lists:
     ...:     count += Counter(sublist)
     ...: 
     ...: print(count)
Counter({'c': 3, 'a': 2, 'b': 1, 'd': 1})
```

This is "one-line-able" using python's builtin `sum`:

```
In [163]: from collections import Counter
     ...: lists = [['a','b','c'], ['a', 'c'], ['c', 'd']]
     ...: 
     ...: count = sum(map(Counter, lists), start=Counter())
     ...: 
     ...: print(count)
Counter({'c': 3, 'a': 2, 'b': 1, 'd': 1})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can flatten the list and use `Counter`. If your list is arbitrarily nested.

```
from collections import Counter
def flatten(lst):
    if not isinstance(lst,list):
        return [lst]
    else:
        return [j for i in lst for j in flatten(i)]

print(Counter(flatten([['a','b','c'], ['a', 'c'], ['c', 'd'] ])))
#Counter({'c': 3, 'a': 2, 'b': 1, 'd': 1})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do by itering in each sublist:

```
dict={} 
for sublist in list:
    for item in sublist:
        if item in dict.keys():
            dict[item] +=1
        else:
            dict[item] =1
```

Answer (score 0):

you can flatten your list and apply `collections.Counter`:

```
from collections import Counter

l = [['a','b','c'], ['a', 'c'], ['c', 'd'] ]
Counter((e for i in l for e in i))
```